# View in ArcGIS JavaScript (Rest/Services) and API's not working with cache tile services

Tags: arcgis-server

In AGS 10.0 I shared the C:/arcgisserver folder, and now my apps and rest endpoints will not display any of my cached services. I can view them fine in ArcCatalog however.  I can build new caches but they are only visible in ArcCatalog.

I am having a similar problem to this post: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/51216-View-in-ArcGIS-JavaScript-(Rest-Services)-not-working-with-cache-tile-services

AGS Site seems to be battling Windows Server for permissions. Here's how my permissions are set up.

```
Name:                    Permission Level
Admin                    Owner
AGS SOC                  Read/Write
AGS SOM                  Read/Write
User                     Read/Write
```

Comment: Did you touch the IIS? Is the folder still seen as a virtual folder in IIS Manager?

Comment: I did not touch IIS. Under my Default Web Site I see the virtual folders arcgiscache, arcgisindex, arcgisjobs, arcgisoutput.